# Copying a few lines from stdout to stderr - but only if stderr is different from stdout

Tags: bash, io-redirection, echo

I have a bash script "backup.sh", which prints out everything to stdout, including all the files that are transferred during backup.

I'd like to make it possible to keep that full output, but when it's called with

```
./backup.sh 2>stderr.log
```

, then only a few important lines from stdout should be copied into stderr.log.

My script currently uses the following function to print out these important lines:

```
errEcho() {
    echo "$1"
    echo "$1" 1>&2
}

echo "Some info message"
errEcho "Very important message"
```

But now, if somebody calls the script simply as

```
./backup.sh
```

Then the errEcho lines appear duplicated on stdout.

What's the best way to solve this? (Effectively, I'd like my script to recognize, if stdout == stderr, and then skip output to stderr, but I'm not sure, if I need a very different approach maybe).

<sub>Please note: I don't want to have two scripts, where one of them calls "backup.sh 2>stderr.log".</sub>

Comment: This is abusing stderr. The reason it exists is to report errors. You should use another file descriptor as an alternate output stream.

Comment: @Keith: That's basically what I mean with my important messages: They're mostly error (or warning) messages. Overall, what I want to achieve is, that when the backup script is run by cron/anacron, the important messages should appear in syslog (but they should not, when the script is run manually).

Comment: @Keith: ... However, I'm not so sure how to do this anyway, I was just looking at some scripts in /etc/cron.daily, and at least some of them send their messages to stderr. Probably you're right: It's better to use a separate descriptor. But how would I best incorporate this into my script (i.e. if it's missing, ignore it, ...)

Comment: @Keith: I think, for the special case of this backup script, you pointed me in the right direction: I'm now simply using `errEcho() { echo "$@" >> /var/log/backup.log ... }` to append to a separate log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearly over-engineering here.

Print information lines *only* to `stdout` and error messages *only* to `stderr`.  Your problem solved.

When you run the script from console and want to hide information messages, use `>/dev/null` redirection: this way you'll only see the error lines.

Comment: I need to see the error messages in ordered context on the console - always, no matter how the user calls the script (except if they use `>/dev/null` of course). Some consoles we're using (especially Java based consoles) process stdout and stderr in parallel (using buffering), so their outputs are interweaved (it's possible, that stderr starts printing in the middle of a line while stdout is writing). With these consoles, you can effectively only receive one stream at a time. This is why the stream must contain all the messages.

Comment: Why not make error message contain the reference to file which caused it?  Like: `/path/to/problematic/file: Permission denied`

Comment: Let's not make this personal.  Don't you see how my answer and comment about putting context into the error stream solve your problem?

Comment: It's certainly helpful in some situations, but it isn't the full solution. The output of one of the streams should give *full* context (meaning: it shows all the preparation steps for the backup, like mounting file systems, then showing all the files that have been processed, and then - in context - the error ), while the other stream should only contain the error message (with a little bit of context information like in your example). In the special case of my backup script, I now chose another solution (see my comments above) - but I'd still like to have a general solution.

Comment: When a user wants both streams, he/she can just run `backup.sh >output.log 2>&1`  That's what he/she would do with any other program and get the expected output log.  So just use `echo` for information and `echo 1>&2` for errors.

Comment: If this is the only possibility, I will have to accept it (and write another wrapper script for each script to simplify the call for everybody who has no idea about the syntax of redirection.)

Comment: I guess anybody who has no idea about redirection syntax doesn't belong to a system where he/she could run that backup script... Just IMO, of course.

Comment: Yeah, the backup script was just an *arbitrary* example. In hindsight, I should have chosen a different one.

Answer (score 1):

```
errEcho () {
  echo 1>&2 "$@"
}
```

Call your script with `backup.sh 2>&1` or just `backup.sh` if you want to see all messages and with `basckup.sh >/dev/null` if you only want error messages.

Comment: Thanks (also for reminding me to use `"$@"`) - the problem which remains is: I'd like to have a way to call the script, so that it prints everything to the console, and only stderr to "stderr.log". Is that possible?